# how to retrieve value from dictionary using joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

i have dictionary like

> **$request = {"Url":"localhost","Database Name":"hotel","Database User":"admin","Password":"a"}**

now i want to fetch value of each key so how to this one is possible with Joomla code.

If any one know please reply me fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done a simple search on Google? Have you tried anything of your own so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Its a json encoded value,

```
   $str = '{"Url":"localhost","Database Name":"hotel","Database User":"admin","Password":"a"}';
    $ar = json_decode($str);
    echo "<pre/>";
    print_r($ar);
```

The result will be

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [Url] => localhost
    [Database Name] => hotel
    [Database User] => admin
    [Password] => a
)
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: its basics try to use Google you can find many similar Q., No prblm